# SetCookie and expire time in one minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to set input value in cookies and want alert in click function. Also I want to expiration date to cookies. I worked on cookies function but it is giving blank value. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3N5f/)

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,extime)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + extime);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((extime==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

#### Set method:

```js
function setCookie(name, value, days)
{
  var expires;
  if (days)
  {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }

  else
  {
    expires = "";
  }

  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
};
```

#### Get method:

```js
function getCookie(name)
{
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++)
  {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
};
```

I've changed the jsfiddle respectively: http://jsfiddle.net/DVeVm/

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more thing does it expire in one minute

Comment: My example here is in minutes.  
To change to seconds just switch this code:  
`(days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`
with this:  
`(days * 1000)`  
the input is in milliseconds.
And ofcourse change the name of the parameter from `days` to `seconds`